# Errors in building C project in visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

I have project lets say PROJECT in C. It contains a number of header files and source files. I build the project in following way

```
  File->New->project from external files
```

I gave the location of the project files and Name of the project.

Choose the option as  `Console`

and then `finish`

The project is seen in the `solution bar`  with

```
 external dependencies, header and source file.
```

When I build it i get error in header file such as

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/_types.h(15):                      error C2054: expected '(' to follow '__extension__'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stddef.h(73): error C2085:    '__threadid' : not in formal parameter list
 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stddef.h(75): error C2085: '__threadhandle' : not in formal parameter list
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/_types.h(37): error C2085: '_flock_t' : not in formal parameter list  
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/_types.h(40): error C2085: '_iconv_t' : not in formal parameter list
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/unistd.h(15): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter '_environ'
 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/unistd.h(17): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter '_exit'
```

1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/unistd.h(19): error C2085: 'access' : not in formal parameter list

What can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 2):

The `__extension__` keyword is used by gcc to indicate that you **know** that something is an extension but want to use it anyway, and request the compiler not to warn about that.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html

Seems like you include some header that is gcc specific and doesn't work for MSVC.